# views in D7 :: remove doubles in exposed filter list

Tags: 7, views

I have two content types, one (A) refering to the other (B). I also have two languages and I want to create a view where I show a list of all content type nodes of type A with an exposed filter, filtering the refering content type nodes of type B. this will show me all nodes of A that refer to B.
so my filters are

- content type (A)
- language (en)
- refering node (exposed)

this works great but inside my exposed filter list of all nodes of type B every node is shown two times, representing every language translation.
I now want to only show the english nodes of type B in the exposed filter list.  how could I do that?
thnx!

ps: I tried to use the filter groups, but this did not work.

Comment: How are you planning to select the language for the exposed filter?

Comment: I only wanted to show the english (original) ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Views exposed filters block is a Drupal form, one that can be modified via a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) implementation. Here is a simple sample implementation of the more generic hook_form_alter.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function foo_helper_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-content-page') {
    // Do something with mah filters...
  }
}
```

If you are in doubt of what #id to use, you can always just implement this hook, go to your Views page, and watch the output of the $form variable to figure out what is the correct id to use. If you are in D7, the ID you are looking for will most likely be prepended with `views-exposed...`.